# sticky sidebar between header and footer

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

Okay, so I have a sticky side bar that is causing a massive headache. The issue comes about when the `.side-bar-wrapper` is larger in height than `.content`. `.content` contains div's that can be extended to show more content - when they're extended `.content` is now higher than the `.side-bar-wrapper` so I want `.side-bar-wrapper` to be fixed when scrolling down the content.

However I only want it to have a maximum scroll up to the footer. I have put together a https://jsfiddle.net/0s8a038L/3/ to hopefully explain the issue i'm facing a lot better than what I have above.

Comment: Not totally sure what you mean - I will say though, try using `slideToggle()` instead of rolling your own, much simpler as you're already using jQuery http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: Apologies, let me explain a little better. The cut and dry of it is I need the `.side-bar-wrapper` to scroll with the user when the user scrolls past `.side-box-one` and to stop scroll on `.side-bar-wrapper` when the bottom of the `.side-bar-wrapper` element reaches the top of the footer element. Does that make sense or am I talking in riddles?

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked this out. Due to the main content been a variable height dependant on what was loaded to the page I only need the implement a rule to see if the sidebar height was larger than the main content; if it was then I would take off the fixed position of the side bar and reposition it 'normally'.